# How to search for emails in a non standard exchange folder using EWS and powershell

Tags: powershell, exchangewebservices

I want use powershell and EWS (see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dd633710(v=exchg.80).aspx) to search for emails that contain a particular string in the subject line.

My problem is that the emails reside in a user-defined folder in the inbox, rather than in one of the folders listed in the WellKnownFolderName enumeration (see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.wellknownfoldername(v=exchg.80).aspx)

The example code that I have found to search for emails all wants to search in one of these well-known folder names rather than in an arbitrary user-specified folder.

does anyone have some example code that i can use as a reference to figure out how to do this [or does EWS limit you to searching for emails using a well-known folder name only].

My code so far is thus:

```
$email    = "myemail@someplace.com"
$username = "myusername" 
$password = "*****"
$domain   = "mydomain"
$USER_DEFINED_FOLDER_IN_MAILBOX = "myRandomFolder"

$EXCHANGE_WEB_SERVICE_DLL = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Exchange\Web Services\1.2\Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.dll"
# load the assembly
[void] [Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFile($EXCHANGE_WEB_SERVICE_DLL)

# set ref to exchange
$s = New-Object Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ExchangeService

# use first option if you want to impersonate, otherwise, grab your own credentials
$s.Credentials = New-Object Net.NetworkCredential($username, $password, $domain)

# discover the url from your email address
$s.AutodiscoverUrl($email)

# get a handle to the inbox
$inbox = [Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.Folder]::Bind($s,[Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.WellKnownFolderName]::Inbox)

$MailboxRootid = new-object  Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.FolderId([Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.WellKnownFolderName]::Root, $email) # selection and creation of new root
$MailboxRoot = [Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.Folder]::Bind($s,$MailboxRootid)

$fvFolderView = new-object Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.FolderView(100) #page size for displayed folders
$fvFolderView.Traversal = [Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.FolderTraversal]::Deep; #Search traversal selection Deep = recursively
$SfSearchFilter = new-object Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.SearchFilter+IsEqualTo([Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.FolderSchema]::Displayname,$NAME_OF_ARCHIVE_FOLDER_IN_MAILBOX) #for each folder in mailbox define search
$findFolderResults = $MailboxRoot.FindFolders($SfSearchFilter,$fvFolderView) 

$ArchiveFolder = ""

# This next loop successfully finds my folder, but it is an inefficient way 
# to do it.  It's ok, because there's not that many folders, but there's tens 
# of thousands of emails to search through in the folder itself, and that will
# need a more efficient search.
foreach ($Fdr in $findFolderResults.Folders)
{
    $theDisplayName = $Fdr.DisplayName
    if($theDisplayName -eq $USER_DEFINED_FOLDER_IN_MAILBOX)
    {
        $ArchiveFolder = $Fdr
    }
}

# Now to actually try and search through the emails in my $ArchiveFolder (the hard way)
$textToFindInSubject = "TEST"

$emailsInFolder = $ArchiveFolder.FindItems(9999)   # <-- Successfully finds ALL emails with no filtering, requiring iterative code to find the ones I want.
foreach($individualEmail in $emailsInFolder.Items)
{
    if($individualEmail.Subject -match "$textToFindInSubject")
    {       
        # found the email i want -  but a super inefficient
        # way to do it
        echo "Successfully found the email!"
    }
}

# Attempt 1 to get the emails with a more refined search
$emailSearchFilter = new-object Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.SearchFilter+ContainsSubstring([Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.EmailMessageSchema]::Subject,$textToFindInSubject) 
$emailsInFolder1 = $ArchiveFolder.FindItems($emailSearchFilter)  # <-- Fails to return an object

# Attempt 2 to get the emails with a more refined search
$iv = new-object Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ItemView(2000)
$emailsInFolder2 = $s.FindItems($ArchiveFolder,  $emailSearchFilter, $iv)   # <-- Also fails to return an object

echo "Done."
```

Thanks heaps :-)

Comment: This code - finds emails in Inbox - but not in the sub-folder (named by the $USER_DEFINED_FOLDER_IN_MAILBOX variable)


`# Attempt 3 to get the emails with a more refined search`
`$ds = new-object Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ItemView(2000)`
`$emailsInFolder3 = $s.FindItems([Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.WellKnownFolderName]::Inbox,  $emailSearchFilter, $ds)  # <-- This works but only for emails directly in Inbox (I have to copy the email into the Inbox folder for it to be found, rather than leaving it in the subfolder I want to search)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.  Here are the lines of code that work [when appended to the initial code]

```
$searchfilter = new-object Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.SearchFilter+ContainsSubstring([Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.EmailMessageSchema]::Subject,$textToFindInSubject)     
$itemView = new-object Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ItemView(999)
$searchResults = $s.FindItems($ArchiveFolder.ID, $searchfilter, $itemView)

foreach($result in $searchResults)
{
    $subj = $result.Subject

    echo "Subject: $subj"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This EWS script lists all folders, including custom ones. I'm running this on our Exchange 2010 SP1 server:

```
Import-Module -Name "C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Exchange Server\V14\ClientAccess\Owa\Bin\Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.dll"
$userEmail = "email.address@domain.com"

$service = New-Object Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ExchangeService([Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ExchangeVersion]::Exchange2010_SP2)
$service.UseDefaultCredentials = $true
$service.AutoDiscoverUrl($userEmail)

$view = New-Object Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.FolderView(100)
$view.PropertySet = New-Object Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.PropertySet([Microsoft.Exchange.Webservices.Data.BasePropertySet]::FirstClassProperties)
$view.PropertySet.Add([Microsoft.Exchange.Webservices.Data.FolderSchema]::DisplayName)
$view.Traversal = [Microsoft.Exchange.Webservices.Data.FolderTraversal]::Deep

$findResults = $service.FindFolders([Microsoft.Exchange.Webservices.Data.WellKnownFolderName]::MsgFolderRoot, $view)

# List all folders
$findResults | select displayname
```